# Will it be possible in the foreseeable future to enforce purity/referential transparency in C++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, language-lawyer, pure-function, referential-transparency

I think I know what *refertially transparent* and *pure* mean. However [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865616/purity-vs-referential-transparency)'s a question about the two properties and how they differ.

As regards how referential transparency and/or purity are enforced in a language, I don't know much. (Not even [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197533/how-is-referential-transparency-enforced) helped me understand.) I mean, I might know (kind of) how Haskell can deal with IO though being purely functional (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117583/is-haskell-truly-pure-is-any-language-that-deals-with-input-and-output-outside/3118369#3118369)), and I understand that I can't write impure functions because the type system just doesn't let me (or, better, it does let me in a controlled way, as I have to write `unsafe` explicitly).

But in C++, like in many other languages, functions are normally non pure nor referentially transparent.

So on the one hand I have Haskell which is constructed as a pure language, where every function is pure. On the other hand I have C++ which has no way to enforce purity (or does it?¹).²

But would it be possible, in the future, for the C++ language to provide a `pure`/whatever attribute that one could attach to a function so that the compiler would have to verify that the function is indeed pure (or compile-time fail otherwise)?

---

(¹) This question popped up in my mind when I first knew of [`[[gnu:pure]]` and `[[gnu:const]]`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes). My understanding is that those (non-portable) attributes are for giving more guarantees to the compiler, so that it can optimize more stuff, not for telling it to check if the function is truly pure. After all [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/PTTrPx6zM) seems to compile and run just fine.

(²) But I also remember another, very old language, which is not pure like Haskell, but gives you a `PURE` attribute to tell that a functions *must* be pure, and the compiler checked it: Fortran.

Comment: Soo have you heard of `constexpr`? As for your question `Will it be possible..` "Yes".  That's not a programming question. Everything is possible.

Comment: _"Will it be possible ..."_ - You are asking an Opinion of people not qualified to answer unless they have some inside/future knowledge of the C++ Standard track.

Comment: There may be a good question somewhere here, but "Is it possible to foresee?" is not a good Stack Overflow question, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe I have to look up what exactly `constexpr` means. For me at the moment it means that _it can be done at compile time_, but from there to _pure_ the jump is a bit big for me atm. Maybe I'll reformulate the question. Will delete for now.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thinking a bit more about it, [I can't make any function `constexpr` just because it's pure](https://godbolt.org/z/e5rexYj9P).